# Ember Transition with query param

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm creating an ember.js app. The first page is single field, with a button. On button click, I'd like it to go to the path `#/deals/:api_key`. However, when I click the button, I'm not clear on the best way to go about it.

Here's what i have so far:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Deal = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('start', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('deals', { path: '/deals/:api_key' });
});

App.DealsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Deal.find();
  }
});

App.StartController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  apiKey: "",
  getDeals: function (model) {
    this.transitionToRoute('deals');
  }
});

App.DealsView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // Add active class to first item
    this.$().find('.item').first().addClass('active');
    this.$().find('.carousel').carousel({interval: 1000});
  }
});

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="start">
    {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="apiKey" placeholder="API Key"}}
    <br />
    <button {{action 'getDeals'}} class="btn btn-large">Get Won Deals!</button>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="deals">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        {{#each model}}
          <div class="item">
            {{name}}
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Any suggestions on the right way to pass data from a text input into the next transition as a query param?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the parameter in the view in a linkTo helper, e.g.

```
{{#linkTo 'deals' api_key}}go to deals{{/linkTo}}
```

this generates a link with the dynamic section you need.

```
<a href="/deals/[the_dynamic_apykey]">go to deals</a>
```

check the docs about linkTo for more info: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Comment: I'm familiar with the `linkTo` helper, was trying to do it through a button action in the controller. I think I figured it out, which uncovered another problem.